# Access `ViewModel` inside `Activity` scoped to navigation graph

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

Inside `Activity` you can get a `ViewModel` scoped to that `Activity` like this:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[ViewModel::class.java] //deprecated way
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ViewModel::class.java]
//or
val viewModel by viewModels<ViewModel>()
```

Similarly in a `Fragment` you can get a `ViewModel` by

```
//scoped to parent Activity
val viewModel: ViewModel by activityViewModels()

//scoped to parent Fragment
val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels({ requireParentFragment() })

//scoped to navigation graph
val viewModel: ViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.login_graph)
```

Now if I try to access a `ViewModel` inside `Activity` which is scoped to a navigation graph then there is no helper method so I have to do

```
val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
            .getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.your_graph).viewModelStore,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
    ).get(ViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Is there a helper method that I have missed? Do I have to access it via navigation graph scope? Can I just use `Activity` scope to access the same `ViewModel`?

Comment: why should the activity know about child's ViewModel scoped to the child? see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741008/accessing-graph-scoped-viewmodel-of-child-navhostfragment-using-by-navgraphviewm